# NGINX UDP Proxy Pass to HTTP

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, http, proxypass, udp

I built a NGINX reverse proxy where I listen for UDP traffic on port 53 and pass it on to an HTTP endpoint with modified headers. Once the headers are modified, I send the packet to the target.

**http.conf**

```
http {  
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;    
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr:$server_port - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';      

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;    

proxy_pass_request_headers on;    

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

keepalive_timeout  120;  
#gzip  on;     

server {
    listen 8080;       
    
    access_by_lua_block
    {             
        ngx.req.set_header("Host", "some_host")
        ngx.req.set_header("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8") 
        ngx.req.set_header("Authorization", "some_token")
    }
   
    location = / {                        
        proxy_pass https://the_real_target;                                                     
               
        }  
    }
}
```

**stream.conf**

```
    stream {
    upstream some_name {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;            
    }           

    server {
        listen      80;      
        proxy_pass  some_name;         
    }

    server {
        listen 53 udp;
        proxy_responses 0; 
        proxy_pass some_name;
    }      
}
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user  nginx;
load_module modules/ndk_http_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_lua_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so;

include conf.d/stream.conf;
include conf.d/http.conf;


worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
```

It works when I use Postman and send requests to port 80. However, when use PacketSender to send request over UDP it is not redirecting to the HTTP server and closes the connection.

I developed a program to test if I can redirect a UDP packet to a TCP endpoint. This works but I am looking for a way to accomplish this only with NGINX. Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt that nginx would do protocol conversions when proxying. The process is quite complex since the protocols are so different. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to solve the problem of receiving TCP packets with signal data and redirect the data to an HTTP target for further processing.

Comment: Is it TCP or UDP? Anyway, since nginx is an HTTP server, and HTTP is specified only to use TCP as a transport, it is the only thing that nginx supports. What is the protocol standard your devices are using to send the signal data over UDP?